# Form marked for deletion but empty FormSet.deleted_forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I've got a piece of code similar to the following:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

EmailFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    MyRelatedModel,
    MyModel,
    form=EmailForm,
    can_delete=True,
    extra=0
)
```

And I've got a custom class-based view which works perfectly fine for creating/saving new `MyModel` instances and for editing existing instances.

When I mark a form / an instance for deletion, I can see my view receives the following POST method:

```
<QueryDict: {
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['XXX'],
  'email-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'],
  'email-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1'],
  'email-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'],
  'email-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'],
  'email-0-id': ['94ef2d4c-b2fc-4082-a460-e4344ddb20d4'],
  'email-0-value': ['12345'],
  'email-0-DELETE': ['on'],
}>
```

I believe this is, again, the expected behavior, in particular the `formset.data` do contain `{'email-0-DELETE': ['on']}` and the form is valid.

**However, the corresponding instance is not deleted. Indeed, when I display `formset.deleted_forms`, it turns out to be an empty list. Why?**

I've tried to deep dive into Django's inner mechanisms and I've noticed the method `deleted_forms` relies on another called `_should_delete_form` which simply returns `form.cleaned_data.get(DELETION_FIELD_NAME, False)`. But in my case, `form.cleaned_data` only contains `{'value': '12345'}`, no "DELETE" key... So how is `_should_delete_form` supposed to return something else than `False`? Am I supposed to explicitly add a `DELETE` field to `EmailForm`, isn't the formset supposed to manage that extra field?

Answer (score 1):

"I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. But recently, I needed to check if I had a deleted form in a submitted formset using **formset.deleted_forms**. However, I was getting an empty list unless all forms were deleted.

In my case, I simply wanted to check if any forms were marked for deletion. So, I used the following line of code:

```
 deleted_forms_exist = any('-DELETE' in key for key in self.request.POST)
```

I'm not sure if this will work for your situation, but it might be worth a try. Good luck!"

Comment: Thanks. I've finally managed to achieve what I wanted. I am quite comfortable with Django now and I'm sure I was facing a 'bug' or at least a edge case introduced by the version 4.1 of the framework, recently released. My issue was indeed more specifically related to the new [validation of constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#validation-of-constraints). `inlineformset_factory` may have a weird behavior when used for a Django model which has an `ExclusionConstraint`... I may open a ticket on the official website when I'll find some time.